# How to use escape characters in Ansible shell/grep command

Tags: shell, ansible, grep, escaping, character

I need to extract a hostname from a URL in a file on my remote host to then use that value in another task.

I have the following task in my playbook:

```
- name: Extract server name
  shell: "grep ^serverURL=https:\/\/(.*)\/XMLRPC <filename>"
  register: <variable>
```

But when I try and run it I get the following error (cut down to relevant bits):

*Found unknown escape character. The offending line appears to be:*

```
- name: Extract server name
  shell: "grep ^serverURL=https:\/\/(.*)\/XMLRPC <filename>"
                                ^ here
```

*It seems there is a value started with a quote and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended with the same kind of quote.*

Obviously it does start and finish with double quotes but the carat is at the escape character in my grep query, so it seems reasonable to think that this is the cause of the problem; if I remove the backslashes my grep query doesn't return anything.

How can I escape this correctly please?

Comment: what is the objective of using `grep` command here? can you add a sample input present in the file and what you need to store in the register? This can be done natively using ansible.

Comment: use "slurp" or just register the output of your command (if it's not a file) and do the job inside Ansible on the registerred variable...

Comment: I believe you are getting bitten by the backslash treatment inside `"` strings in yaml; if you use `shell: 'grep ^serverURL=https:\/\/(.*)\/XMLRPC <filename>'` it will at least move the backslash whining elsewhere (since `/` is not a meta character in any regex so I don't know why it needs any backslashery at all) -- but be careful, `(` and `)` _are_ meaningful to every shell that I know of, and thus they should be treated carefully